# Extract from Array of Rows in Presto

Tags: sql, json, presto

I have a table that has a list of dictionaries. In the example there is only one dictionary in the list.

| items |
| --- |
| [{'a': 'apple', b: 'banana'}] |

I want to sekect the value for 'a', which is apple.

I have tried:
`SELECT json_extract_scalar(json_parse(items), '$.a')` which gives the error:

`Unexpected parameters (array(row("t" varchar,"i" varchar,"p" integer,"v" integer,"s" varchar))) for function json_parse. Expected: json_parse(varchar(x))`

I also tried:
`SELECT TRANSFORM(CAST(JSON_PARSE(items) AS ARRAY<JSON>), x -> JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x, '$.a'))`

which gives the same error. If I do `CAST(items AS varchar)` first, there is an error that says it cannot convert an array to varchar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided error shows that your data is not actually a varchar or json but an array of [`ROW`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/language/types.html#row) with 5 fields (`t`, `i`, `p`, `v`, `s`). Rows can't be easily converted to required json structure, but you can easily access it's fields by name:

```sql
select item.t
from (
    SELECT array [ cast (row('apple', 'banana') as row(t varchar, i varchar)) ] items -- shortened sample data
) 
cross join unnest(items) as c(item) -- flatten the array
```

Output:

| t |
| --- |
| apple |